# Can I Make a Div tag out of master page placeholder?

Tags: asp.net, css, contentplaceholder

in my asp.net project i use a master page and that have a contentplaceholder;
in my child pages, i want make a div tag and it should contain all of my window (width:100%; height:100%;).
but when i create this div tag its in my ContentPlaceHolder and isn't full screen.
Can i make this out of ContentPlcaeHolder ?

Comment: have you set the dimensions for the placeholder?

Comment: my PlaceHolder is in a table cell and this cell has set size (width: ...; height: ...;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get this `div` wrapped around the content of all the child pages, I would suggest just wrapping the `ContentPlaceHolder` in a `div` in your master page.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Then apply `css` to `#wrapper`.